# Is there a way to generically represent a group of similar functions?

Tags: go, interface, generic-programming

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Pet interface {
    Bark()
}

type Dog int

func (d Dog) Bark() {
    fmt.Println("W! W! W!")
}

type Cat int

func (c Cat) Bark() {
    fmt.Println("M! M! M!")
}

type AdoptFunc func(pet Pet)

func adoptDog(dog Dog) {
    fmt.Println("You live in my house from now on!")
}
func adoptCat(cat Cat) {
    fmt.Println("You live in my house from now on!")
}

func main() {
    var adoptFuncs map[string]AdoptFunc
    adoptFuncs["dog"] = adoptDog // cannot use adoptDog (type func(Dog)) as type AdoptFunc in assignment
    adoptFuncs["cat"] = adoptCat // the same as above
}
```

As the code above, is there a way to use a map or array to collect a bunch of similar functions adoptXxx? If not, what is right pattern to use for this situation?

Comment: Make `adoptCat` accept a `Pet` instead of a `Cat`. In general: Forget about inheritance and classical OOP and redesign. IMHO pets, cats and dogs make bad examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use the map as a function collection you'll have to change the signature of your functions to match. `func(Pet)` is not the same type as `func(Dog)`.

You can re-write `AdoptXXX` functions to take in `Pet` and do a type select to ensure correct pet is being input:

```
func adoptDog(pet Pet) {
    if _, ok := pet.(Dog); !ok {
        // process incorrect pet type
    }
    fmt.Println("You live in my house from now on!")
}
```

Comment: Conversion from pet to Dog is an easy thing to do. If for example, the equivalent is unmarshalling of a bytes slice to a ProtoBuffer message, I also have to do it in every OnXxxMessage-like functions?

Comment: Unmarshaling is not exactly type conversion since protobuf message is simply a sequence of bytes. Unmarshal function reads this sequence and populates another data structure with it. Interfaces are used to define an expected behavior. If a type implements an interface, then it has the behavior of that interface. So that means if multiple concrete types can exhibit same behavior (though they may implement it differently), you should use interfaces to hold the types, calling their methods as required.

Comment: In your specific example, `OnXxxMessage` function would take the message and pass it on to each pet listening for messages. That means each `OnXxxMessage` can work directly with `Pet` interface as long as you supply the interface with something like a `ProcessMessage()` method.

Comment: What if each `OnXxxMessage` needs its specific information?

Comment: Can you update your question to explain exactly what you require?